# MS Exchange 2016 and high memory usage

Tags: exchange, memory

Our MS Exchange 2016 instalation has a high memory usage in store worker and sometines this stop to receive then email from another server. What may be wrong in our instalation?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's normal for Store Worker / Exchange to use a lot of memory if it's available, and then return it when needed elsewhere, so I'd suspect your issue is elsewhere. When it fails to accept email, what errors are you seeing in the logs and what's being reported to the sending server? Note, "memory" errors relating to Back Pressure can sometimes be caused by available disk space, not system memory.

Comment: 24 GB RAM does not seem high for an Exchange server really. You might just need more RAM

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above, this is normal. Exchange acts as a memory management system. It takes as much ram as possible, then gives it back to the system.